How to set maximum height of Image in SliverAppBar when scrolling down, Keep image in Appbar when scrolling up using CustomScrollView
I'm a Flutter user to develop apps on the Android platform, I want to create a screen that displays playlist details, I tried using CustomScrollView to design but it doesn't work and I get the following errors.
I use (physics) to turn on the slider and it's not what I expected, I used (flexibleSpace) to set the image for the app but when I drag it up, the image doesn't retain the app bar. The screen displaying details of this playlist I took as reference from the music listening application "NetEase Cloud Music" (网易云音乐), link APP(https://music.163.com/), I posted it here to ask for opinions and help everyone or is there any way to create the same? Is it like this screen? I sincerely thank everyone for reading.
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
